# Post many to many relationship with extra column

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many, postman, hibernate-mapping

in my spring boot application i have 2 entities "**Student**" and "**Course**" ( student may love many courses and course may be loved by many student)
so i added entity "CourseRating" for this relationship and i add an other column in this entity (Rating)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feU0Q.png)

i'm using Postman to send Http requests to my rest APi 
in my data base i have already the list of courses
now my problem is how to send a post request to add new student who like (maths & physics) and his rating = 16 in maths and = 18 in physics

```js
@Embeddable
class CourseRatingKey implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    Long studentId;
 
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    Long courseId;
 
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
    // hashcode and equals implementation
}
```

```js
@Entity
class CourseRating {
 
    @EmbeddedId
    CourseRatingKey id;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("student_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    Student student;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("course_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    Course course;
 
    int rating;
     
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

```js
class Student {
 
    // ...
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    Set<CourseRating> ratings;
 
    // ...
}
 
class Course {
 
    // ...
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    Set<CourseRating> ratings;
 
    // ...
```

Comment: The model you use does not respond to your needs. I suggest to look at manytomany relation.

Comment: could you explain more please ?

Comment: there is a native @manyTomany annotation. Did you try it ?

Comment: Any solutions??